# multiparty error in parsing callback request

Tags: node.js, multiparty

I am using multiparty. It was working fine but suddenly it is throwing error.

**Error**

```
err: { Error: stream ended unexpectedly
    at Form.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:754:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Form.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:514:14)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:524:3)
    at Form.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:489:5)
    at onend (_stream_readable.js:511:10)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) status: 400, statusCode: 400 }
```

**Code**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
                                               var body = "";
                                               var POST = {};
                                               var form = new multiparty.Form();
                                               form.on('error', function(err) {
                                                       console.log('Error parsing form: ' + err.stack);
                                                       });
                                               form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files) {
                                                          response.status(500).send({
                                                                                    message: err
                                                                                    });
                                                          })
                                               });
});
```

Comment: Hey. I'm facing the same issue here. You were able to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of issue.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846002/unable-to-upload-file-to-server-using-node-js-and-react-native ~> These one, Sunny Shah

Answer (score 3):

The *"stream ended unexpectedly"* error implies the underlying TCP socket was closed before a complete multipart form was received.

As you say this was previously working you should check the server to which you are making the request for any errors which may be closing the response early. One common cause is the size of the response data being larger than accepted by the server or request/response headers.